# how to add joss5.1.0GA in netbeans

Tags: web-server

I use netbeans6.8 ide.
In that i want to add jboss 5.1.0ga as server.
I have jboss 5.1.0GA.src.tar.gz file.
This file is enough or i want download any other file.
tell how to add jboss and how install jboss5.1.0GA?
how can i specify jboss server location?.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it myself, but it should be just a matter of emulating whats in the jboss/bin/run.bat file.  Your project needs to launch the org.jboss.Main class, which in turn calls your project classes.

```
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS%" 
-classpath "%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%" org.jboss.Main %*
```